# What is Delphi equivalent to "fsockopen" function in php?

Tags: php, delphi

What is Delphi equivalent to "fsockopen" function in php?

in [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php):

```
resource fsockopen ( string $hostname [, int $port = -1 [, int &$errno [, string &$errstr     [, float $timeout = ini_get("default_socket_timeout") ]]]] )
Initiates a socket connection to the resource specified by hostname.
```

My code is fully:

```
function accountcreate($username, $password, $connection, $bandwidth, $disabledate,  $disabletime)
{
$adminpassword='';
$adminport=82;
$proxyaddress='127.1.1.1';

$fp = fsockopen($proxyaddress, $adminport, &$errno, &$errstr, 1000);
if(!$fp) 
{
        echo "$errstr ($errno)<br>\n";
} 
else 
{
    $url_ = "/account";
    $url = "add=1"."&";
    .
    .
    $url = $url."userid=-1";
    $len = "Content-Length: ".strlen($url);
    $auth = "Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode("admin:".$adminpassword);
    $msg = "POST ".$url_." HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: ".$proxyaddress."\r\n".$auth."\r\n".$len."\r\n"."\r\n".$url;
    fputs($fp,$msg);
    echo $msg;

    fclose($fp);
}
```

that code make a new account in ccproxy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how i can convert this php code to delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982458/how-i-can-convert-this-php-code-to-delphi)

Comment: No, @John, it's not a duplicate. The other question was closed because it was so broad in what it asked for. This is much more specific.

Comment: Fair enough. That's why it takes 5 votes to close and not one. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps have a look at the Indy Components that ship with Delphi (assuming at least Delphi7).  You would need :

[TIdTCPConnection Documentation](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=TIdTCPConnection.html)

which contains an `IOHandler` property (TIdIOHandler) where you specify the parameters used in `fsockopen`:

[TIdTCPConnection.IOHandler Property](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=TIdTCPConnection_IOHandler.html)

[TIdIOHandler Documentation](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=TIdIOHandler.html)

As others have noted, however, you probably would be well served by looking at the bigger picture in your PHP code and perhaps implementing its functionality with a higher level tool like `TIdHTTP` :

[TIdHTTP Documentation](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=TIdHTTP.html)

Comment: I bet all of this is not needed as because from the previous question it looks that OP wants to do the HTTP POST, so I would suggest to use the `TIdHTTP` here since PHP does this in a different way. Nothing against your post since you are trying to answer what is being asked here.

Comment: @TLama yes, I saw the other question and I agree that he's probably trying to POST (and should do as you suggest).  I suppose it wouldn't hurt to include it.